# Where can i download ICDAR pictures dataset from 2003 to 2015?

Tags: dataset

I need scene text pictures for evaluating the result of my OCR app so i want ICDAR picture datasets from 2003 to 2015, Please provide url or download link.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find such site collecting all Robust Reading datasets, but I can still find some datasets with a simple DuckDuckGo search:
[ICDAR 2003 Robust Reading Competition](http://iapr-tc11.org/mediawiki/index.php?title=ICDAR_2003_Robust_Reading_Competitions)
[ICDAR 2011-2017 Robust Reading Competitions](http://rrc.cvc.uab.es)
Hope you Google or Bing it first before you ask next time.